# Dramatically slow copying(?) to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working with hyperspectral image of size [610, 340, 102] from [here](http://www.ehu.eus/ccwintco/index.php?title=Hyperspectral_Remote_Sensing_Scenes#Pavia_University_scene) saved in .mat file. After loading it with scipy, it is represented as array. Prior to make computations I have to reshape it to [610 * 340, 102]. The code below is running on desktop machine with i5-6400 processor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.io as spio
import time

pavia_u = spio.loadmat("./../data/PaviaU.mat")["paviaU"]
original_shape = tf.shape(pavia_u)
pavia_u_reshaped = tf.to_float(tf.squeeze(tf.reshape(pavia_u, [-1, original_shape[0] * original_shape[1], original_shape[2]])))

with tf.Session() as session:
    start = time.clock()
    pavia_u_reshaped_value = session.run(pavia_u_reshaped)
    end = time.clock()
    print("Reshape time: {}".format(end - start))
```

and it prints: `Reshape time: 157.7449091748693`

It seems that reshape operation on so relative small dataset should not be so slow. Anyway, I moved reshaping to numpy a

```
pavia_u = spio.loadmat("./../data/PaviaU.mat")["paviaU"]
original_shape = pavia_u.shape
pavia_u_reshaped = pavia_u.reshape([-1, original_shape[0] * original_shape[1], original_shape[2]]).squeeze())

with tf.Session() as session:
    start = time.clock()
    session.run(tf.identity(pavia_u_reshaped))
    end = time.clock()
    print("Test time: {}".format(end - start))
```

which prints: `Test time: 143.26529380869727`

What consumes so much time now? How to fix this.

Comment: there's a bunch of initializations that get run on the first session.run call, what if you run it twice and benchmark both calls

Comment: I have measured 4 sequential calls of `session.run(tf.identity(pavia_u_reshaped))` and the test printed `Test time: 562.1225702215002`

Answer (score 1):

Reshape is not the reason for the slow time, its the initialisations that is taking time. Changing the code to :

```
original_shape = tf.shape(pavia_u)
X = tf.Variable(pavia_u, dtype=tf.float32)

pavia_u_reshaped = tf.to_float(tf.squeeze(tf.reshape(X, [-1, original_shape[0] * original_shape[1], original_shape[2]])))


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
start = time.clock()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
end = time.clock()
print("Initialization time: {}".format(end - start))

start = time.clock()
pavia_u_reshaped_value = sess.run(pavia_u_reshaped)
end = time.clock()
print("Reshape time: {}".format(end - start))

# Initialization time: 734.495346
# Reshape time: 1.897106
```

Comment: Thank you! But why it is so slow? Is there way to speedup the initialization?